# Which Psudo-Random Number Generation algorithm does RNGCryptoServiceProvider use?

Tags: .net, security, c#-4.0, cryptography

There are many proven and well established Psudo-Random Number Generation algorithms available for use, and others that have come under recent scrutiny; I was wondering which algorithm the .Net 4.0 RNGCryptoServiceProvider uses?

I am keen to know the answer to this before I put an ongoing project live.

Many Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [CryptGenRandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom).  It gets it from the Crypto API, which is included in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

By inspection of the code, it *defaults* to `PROV_RSA_AES` or `PROV_RSA_FULL` depending on the operating system, but you can pass in your own `CspParameters` instance specifying the algorithm from [list list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.providertype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The docs for [PROV_RSA_AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [PROV_RSA_FULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) don't mention the generator. Would they use `CryptGenRandom` since nothing special is called out?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also found this page which gives a better description of the available providers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375729%28v=vs.85%29.aspx